# why $\pi_1(T) \cong \mathbb{Z}?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have  some  confusion on this  [pdf](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Emaraston/Topologia2/Topo2_1011_vankampen_covering_examples.pdf)(page no$:4$)

It is written that

> compute $\pi_1(X) $  where $ X= \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S^1$

> take  $U=X \setminus \mathbb{R}_z$ where  $\mathbb{R}_z =\{(x,y,x)\in \mathbb{R}^3 :x=y=0\}$

> $V= \{(x,y,x)\in \mathbb{R}^3 :x^2+y^2<1\}$

> setting $T= \{(x,y,x)\in \mathbb{R}^3 :x>0,y=0\} \setminus\{(1,0,0)\}$

> then $U $ is homeomorphic to $T \times S^1$

> hence $\pi(U)\cong \pi_1(T) \times \pi_(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

**My confusion**: why $\pi_1(T) \cong \mathbb{Z}?$

$T$ is  not look like  a circle .Then  why $\pi_1(T) \cong \mathbb{Z}?$

Also,Im not able to visualize the diagram  of $T$

Comment: $T$ looks like a punctured half-plane, which is homeomorphic to a plane punctured at the origin, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, via  a homotopy that maps $z$ to $tz$.

Comment: okay thanks you@RobArthan

Comment: My description of the relevant homotopy wasn't right, but I hope you got the general idea. (I should have written $z \mapsto $z/(t|z| + 1 - t)$.)